# Report Expressions -group total row on calculated columns- SSRS2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am developing report in sql server 2012(using report wizard) which has 5 columns which are calculated at run time in tablix table.

They are grouped by row wise and total row should appear in the group total's row.

I am trying to give the expression to find column sum as  "Sum(ReportItems!totalcolumn1.Value)". Report throws an error for aggregate function not allowed in tablix. Please suggest ,what would be the best method to find sum of the calculated columns?

my calculated column b2 has the formula : =

```
IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!AgeDueDate.Value),
  IIF(((Parameters!AgeBreaks.Value(0) = 1 AND Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value > Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value(0) ) OR
                                (Parameters!AgeBreaks.Value(0) > 1 AND Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value> Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value(0) AND Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak2.Value(0)))
                                ,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value,0),
                                IIF(
                                (Parameters!AgeBreaks.Value(0) = 1 AND Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value > Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value(0) ) OR
                                ( Parameters!AgeBreaks.Value(0) > 1 AND Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value> Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value(0) AND Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak2.Value(0))                                ,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value,0)
                                )
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What expressions are you using?

Comment: Hi, Please find the attached picture of my expression passed in the report

Comment: Share the expressions for the calculated columns.

Comment: please find my updated question, my column has the calculations as above and works fine. I need to get sum of all these calculated column in rowtotal

Comment: I have now added my column b2 as calculated field in dataset and have the same formula. but it still doesnot work.